# Set two background colour in table cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've to design `UITableViewCell` like [image: this image]

Please not that the time label and text label have different background, and also alternate cell has different colours as well.

I tried to set background colour for each `UILabel` in cell. Is there a better option available? Please note that i'm supporting all the iOS devices.Please suggest.

**Edit:** for better understanding about my question, i'm using this code-

```
if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0) {
    // Even : Set Even color combination to both labels
}
else    {
    // Odd : Set Even color combination to both labels
}
```

Now the real question- is this best way? means if i set background colour for labels in each cell won't it effect scrolling performance?

Comment: Well it's the colour of the cell, not the label within the cell, that will enable that effect.  They look like the same type of cell to me; but configured differently.

Comment: Can you reformulate your question please? What is your real issue here?

Comment: The question is what is the best way to achieve this design?I'm using two labels with different background colour in each cell.

Comment: each Cell have different color or only this two color use in tableview

Comment: Only these two colour are used in alternate basis, means these two cell will repeat one after another.

Comment: I saw this on apple's developer site. i have been using this and have not experienced any lags/performance issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You can set background color to your label to implement this design.
You need to check the alternate cell to set either color.

For this simply use mod to check indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0) {
    // Even : Set Even color combination to both labels
}
else    {
    // Odd : Set Odd color combination to both labels
}
```

Comment: I've implemented as you suggest, but my question is that is this best way? means if i set background colour for labels in each cell won't it effect scrolling performance?

Comment: There will be zero affect on performance if you are using ReusableCell. Your tableview will load only those cell which are visible on screen. Even if you have 1000 item to show allocated number of cell will same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need to make static `UIColor` objects somewhere in `viewDidLoad` that it'll initialize only once.

```
static UIColor *oddColor = ...;
static UIColor *evenColor = ...;
```

then, you can update it in your code, its perfect. In this way, those color objects will only create for once and you'll use the same color in your cell. So it chance to have good performance while scrolling.

However, if there's not big count of cells you don't need to use static. Just keep it as it is.